# What word class is 恥ずべき?

Tags: grammar, nominalization

恥ずべき is listed as an adjective in EDICT, as a 'compound word' (連語) in kotobank ([here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%81%A5%E3%81%9A%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D-358568#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)), and as a "noun or verb acting pre-nominally" on the Midori app. My question relates to a sample sentence I saw on EDICT ([link](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1Q%C3%D1%A4%BA%A4%D9%A4%AD_1_)).

> > 君は、自分の愚かさを恥ずべきだ。You should be ashamed of your folly.

All the other examples I found are `恥ずべき+Noun` (恥ずべき秘密, 恥ずべき行為, 恥ずべきこと, etc), making them noun phrases. But in the above example 恥ずべき is followed by the copula だ. Also, the inclusion of the particle を would seem to make it a verbal use of 恥ずべき since there is no other verb present.

So is that example sentence correct? If so, how is 恥ずべき functioning grammatically with を and the copula だ?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18642/how-to-negate-%e3%81%b9%e3%81%8d-ie-should-not https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/7048/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%81%b9%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%9a-and-%e3%81%b9%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%96%e3%82%8b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「恥ずべき」 is a combination of the verb **恥ず** and the auxiliary verb **べし**.

https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B9%E3%81%97

Both of these words follow somewhat archaic grammar patterns, so they don't behave like most modern verbs.

- 恥ずべき functions with を because it is a verb taking a direct object
- 恥ずべき functions with the copula だ because べき is the form of the auxiliary verb べし that attaches to the copula

Comment: Ok I understand it can take を if it functions as a verb and it can be followed by だ when it is nominalized as べき. But how can it be **both** at the same time?

Comment: べき isn't a nominalized form, but rather a "linking" form, so 恥ずべき remains a verb and is "linked" to the copula.

Comment: Ok, I was seeing it as a nominalized form rather a verb.

Comment: The べき in this case is the 残存形 of the verb べし.

Comment: べき used with だ behaves like a 形容動詞 (na-adjective)

Comment: Thinking about it, I actually use ～をすべきだ myself in speech. I didn't even realize it was the same form. I guess I'm not used to seeing ～べき other than すべき.

Comment: Good point! Even in the case of すべき it is す + べき (archaic grammar strikes again)